# Bootstrap navigation bar modification

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need your help, please...

Anyone here comrehends/uses Bootstrap? I've tinkered with one of the sample fluid navbar I took from Bootstrap. I want to modify some of the navbar formation in wide/normal format but still remain the same when it's altered to fluid format. I've tried tinkering with the coding, but I just ruined it. I am really lost what I have to do... -_-

Here the link of the bootstrap fluid navbar I want to modify: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

And below is the picture of the modification I want it to be...

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxP0vOY-BogNbjBPczg5SmhuZFU/edit

Please, help me. It'll be much appreciated :D

Comment: your second link dont work

Comment: sorry... it does now...

Comment: what is the difference

Comment: see... the Default, Static top, Fixed top bee deleted (i just deleted)

"The project name" is aligned to the right, meanwhile "Home, about, contact, and dropdown" aligned in the left...
But the hierarcy has to stay the same that "Home, about, contact, and dropdown" are inside the "The project name". So when it goes fluid, only "The project name" will show up and the "Home, about, contact, and dropdown" hide inside it unless "The project name" is clicked...